# Github Action that runs on Pull Request from a particular head branch, to a particular base branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I'd like a Github action to run on Pull Request to a specific base branch, but *from* another specific head branch.

```
name: Run production tests

on:  
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs: ...
```

However, I specifically want something like this to run when a branch called `develop` is PR'd against `main`, not just every time something is PR'd to `main`.

Is such a workflow possible? I might be missing it, but I don't see a way to target head branches in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation, I could not find any filters for the head branch. But this is doable with `if` conditions for jobs.
For example

```
name: Run production tests

on:  
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs: 
  build:
    if: ${{ github.head_ref == 'develop'}}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Run a multi-line script
        run: |
          echo "Do something here"
```

Comment: Note that `head_ref` is only available on `pull_request`, but not on `push`: https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.2/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context